# Installing Grub on btrfs /boot when root is on ZFS

Tags: grub2, 22.04, grub-efi, zfs, btrfs

I'd like to use Grub for booting my Ubuntu 22.04 system. The system has its root filesystem on a ZFS dataset, it has the usual EFI boot partition, and a btrfs partition that can be used as `/boot`. When the system is booted up and I have both `/boot` and `/boot/efi` mounted, running `update-grub` prints the following error and then only installs the fallback "UEFI Firmware Settings" entry:

```
Found linux image: vmlinux-5.15.0-101-generic in rpool/UBUNTU
Found initrd image: initrd.img-5.15.0-101-generic in rpool/UBUNTU
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: unknown filesystem.
```

I understand that Grub doesn't have complete ZFS support, but that's exactly why I have this extra btrfs partition for `/boot`! I am baffled why the ZFS stuff even factors into booting here -- I thought Grub would load the initrd from `/boot` and then the rest of the process would be taken care of by Linux itself.

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?